# Can I run SQL Server Management Studio in Windows 7?

Tags: sql-server, windows-7

I've recently upgraded my OS to Windows 7, but this new OS wouldn't let me install SQL Server Management Studio. Is there a way to get around it?

Comment: Which version of SQL Mgmt Studio?  I have installed SQL 2008 mgmt studio on Windows 7 32bit/64bit.

Comment: you'd help yourself if you described the error....

Comment: Sql Management studio is also a tool used by developers to do dev work.

Comment: @Darrel: if he were asking how to use SQL Management Studio to do dev work, I'd agree.

Comment: @john Those questions will be coming next, once he has figured out how to install it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm running Windows 7 with SQL Server 2005. You have to install a couple of the SQL Server SP's. You can find some good trouble shooting tips here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955725/EN-US.

Answer (score 0):

You must install it as administrator.  **It's not enough to be logged in to the administrator account.**  You must all right-click on the installer file and choose the "Run as Administrator" option.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, verify that this is what you are trying to install:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=08e52ac2-1d62-45f6-9a4a-4b76a8564a2b&displaylang=en

I am running Windows 7 Ultimate on a virtual machine on my MacBook and have SQL EXPRESS 2008 installed along with SQL Management Studio without any problems. I downloaded SQL Management Studio from the link above.

Note: I also had to install SQL Express 2008 SP1 before installing SQL Management Studio from here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=01AF61E6-2F63-4291-BCAD-FD500F6027FF&displaylang=en

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just to let you know, the Express version of Management Studio is a different product. It is a stripped down version of what is included with the full versions of SQLServer.

Comment: @Joe Thanks, I am aware of that and I am glad you posted this comment so everyone else is aware of it too :)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 RTM will not install on to Windows 7.

But SQL Server 2008 RTM with slipstreamed SP1 *will*. So you need to create a slipstreamed install, this is not hard (with a little care and attention). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638062.aspx), [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/petersad/archive/2009/02/25/sql-server-2008-creating-a-merged-slisptream-drop.aspx) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/petersad/archive/2009/04/24/sql-server-2008-slipstream-frequently-asked-questions.aspx) for details (the first is to the official instructions, but I found the latter two links helpful in clarifying things).

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing through the Web Platform Installer. I just used the tool to install SQL 2008 and Management Studio, without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the word from Microsoft for the proper steps: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/6a569376-4207-4184-a8a7-73d5168c787e  Just follow the directions there and you should have no problem getting it to install.

This is more oriented for VS with SQL, but just replace the related steps with doing the steps within the SQL installer basically.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use the 32bit version on win7 (It's under options in the first window of the setup of sql server). While the 64bit versions rule checks fail. It works just fine with the 32bit version.

Hope this helps.