# Install Sql Server Developer Edition 32-bit (or Enterprise Edition) on Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, sql-server-2008, 64-bit

Is there any work around to Successfully install SQL server 2008 32-bit on Windows 7 Home premium 64-bit ?
If this is the case I first installed VS 2008 SP 1 on my machine and when I click on install.exe file for installing SQL Server 2008 (Developer Edition) I get an error related to .NET Framework version which is installed already on my PC. { I get the same error trying to install Enterprise Edition}

Answer (score 1):

You need to slipstream SP1 into the install (this is also needed for the 64bit install).

See [Can I run SQL Server Management Studio in Windows 7?](https://serverfault.com/questions/107792/can-i-run-sql-server-management-studio-in-windows-7/107836#107836)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the official word from Microsoft: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssetup/thread/6a569376-4207-4184-a8a7-73d5168c787e

Definitely will need to have SQL2008 with SP1 (whether already there or slip-streamed like Richard said)

I am running two instances of 2008 dev on my Win7 laptop without issue though, so once you get SP1 in the mix you should be fine.

Comment: By the way, forgot to mention that this link is related to VS+SQL, you just need to follow the SQL specific steps and instead of using the VS installer, you would be using the SQL installer.

Direct link to the slipstream doc: http://blogs.msdn.com/petersad/archive/2009/02/25/sql-server-2008-creating-a-merged-slisptream-drop.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different versions of the 32-bit SQL 2008 installer.   There is a WOW version and a non-WOW version  (related to AWE memory management I think).  Youre probably trying the wrong one?